# Is the `that` in phrase `Only the best product that can survive` properly used?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

I searched online that the word `that` has a function of `stress/emphasize`.
And this usage comes up to my mind when designing for our company motto.
Is it proper here?

---

The colleague edition:

```
Two steps ahead to think and design in rapidly changing market
Solving problems instead of analysing difficulty
Working, sharing and studying in the elite team
Embrace the trial of business startups, total devotion
Only the best product that can survive
```

My edition:

```
Think two steps ahead than the market.
Solving problems instead of explaining.
Keep learning, share your experiences.
Embrace the challenge with fully devotion.
Only the best product can survive.
```

Comment: This is proofreading, but I question the wisdom of attempting to create slogans/mottos in a foreign language (foreign to OP, I mean).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, the BOSS requires some international flavor, you know that. I gave the whole slogan just for context. If you think that's sort of abuse, I could withdraw the last paragraph.

Comment: This is far too long to be a motto or a slogan. This is more like a poem.

Comment: Or potentially 5 separate mottos (one motto per line)

Comment: And I would remove "that" whether its proper or in-proper on the premise that it sounds weird and makes less sense.

Comment: This business starting,
So much devotion needed:
Better stay in bed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, this whole passage makes very little sense. Adding "that" seems unnecessary, as it doesn't make too much of a difference in how it reads.